# Problems with linebreaks in navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm searching and trying for hours now but I don't get it to work.

I have an "inline-form" with a button on the left, an input field in the middle and a button on the right in a navbar. It's displayed the right way when the navbar isn't collapsed.

But when I collapse the menu then I get linebreaks near each button. But I want to have all three controls in one line.

[It looks like this in the navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImCkp.jpg)

[And it looks like that in the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biJym.jpg)

Edit: I found out that this problem only occurs at the "sm"-break when the "input-group" gets a width of 100 %.

I'm using this code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-hv-dark-green sticky-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand h1 mb-0 mr-5" href="/">
    <img alt="" class="d-inline-block mr-1" height="35" src="img/brand.svg" />
    <span class="align-bottom">PAGE TITLE</span>
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarContent" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarContent">
    <div class="form-inline ml-auto">
      <button class="btn btn-danger mr-2" onclick="clear()" title="clear" type="button">
        <span class="fas fa-user-slash fa-fw"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="input-group my-2">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text">
            <span class="fas fa-money-bill-wave"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control text-right" id="total" readonly="readonly" type="number" value="0.00" />
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <span class="input-group-text">
            <span class="fas fa-euro-sign"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button class="btn btn-warning ml-md-2" onclick="save()" title="save" type="button">
        <span class="fas fa-save fa-fw"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex-nowrap` on the `form-inline` to prevent wrapping...

```
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarContent">
        <div class="form-inline flex-nowrap ml-auto">
            <button class="btn btn-danger mr-2" onclick="clear()" title="clear" type="button">
                <span class="fas fa-user-slash fa-fw"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="input-group my-2">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text">
                        <span class="fas fa-money-bill-wave"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control text-right" id="total" readonly="readonly" type="number" value="0.00">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text">
            <span class="fas fa-euro-sign"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-warning ml-2" onclick="save()" title="save" type="button">
                <span class="fas fa-save fa-fw"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/VqsFCA8SMq

Comment: Could it be so easy? Yes! Thank you! :)